# Numpy array indexing manipulation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So let's say we have

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

How would we make it so that at index n the number is changed to -1 and then all numbers to the right of it(higher index) change by -1

For example, n = 3 new array would look like this:

```
[0 1 2 -1 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: It is an easy task to do. What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

```
arr[i], arr[i + 1:] = -1, arr[i + 1:] - 1
```

I suggest you read the docs on [Array Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. I am pretty stupid and even after reading  the docs I don't seem to understand how you got to do it.
The first part is start, the second part is very confusing to me, third part I understand.
For example how would we do it without changing nth index to -1 so just taking all elements after nth index and lowering them by 1?

Comment: It's two statements, `arr[i] = -1` and `arr[i+1:] = arr[i+1:]-1`  The second part is just replacing all the values after index `i` with values that are one  less